# How would I connect to multiple servers with one client in python?

Tags: python, sockets, server, client

I have 2 python files, one client, one server. If I had multiple server files, how would I connect to all of them with one client and send a message to all of them.

Comment: As a starter, show us the relevant code you are using to connect to one server!

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are using the socket library. If this is the case, it's not possible to connect to multiple servers at a time. You would need to create one socket object for each server you are trying to connect.

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: Create a list in your client class which is going to contain all the socket objects. Though, I don't get why you would need to connect to multiple servers at a time...

Comment: @MrtzDev With what library would it be possible to have one client connencted to multiple servers?

Comment: You don't need any other library. Just create multiple connections (socket objects) with the built-in socket module.